# loopback gets errors when slc run after installing socket.io

Tags: socket.io, loopbackjs, strongloop

After I install socket.io, when I run the loopback API, it gives the following errors. I have tried to uninstall the socket.io or re-install the loopback but it still happens. BTW, I can access the API without any problems but it keeps to show so many errors in the console. So, How should I solve this errors?

```
INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'Xamarin_Node_API' pid '4076'
INFO strong-agent[4076] started profiling agent
INFO supervisor reporting metrics to `internal:`
supervisor running without clustering (unsupervised)
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Error: Cannot GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=635806057373451120-193&b
64=1
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback
\server\middleware\url-not-found.js:15:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modul
es\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modu
les\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopba
ck\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\exp
ress\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\l
ib\router\index.js:618:15
    at next (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\exp
ress\lib\router\index.js:256:14)
    at Function.handle (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_
modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (G:\Users\MM\Xamarin_Node_API\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\e
xpress\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
```

Comment: Did you install socket.io globally with `npm install -g socket.io` ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Same issue here. Did anybody solve it? On my side, it's not related to socket.io. I did an update of slc.

Comment: any news on this ?

Comment: Getting the same issue. Any updates?